# Angular2 passing string parameter to PUT webapi null

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi in asp.net core and the action method definition is

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCaseStatus(int id, [FromBody] string status)
{

}
```

When i try to call this method from my angular2 app, the string value is always null. Can anyone help me what am i doing wrong here?

Here is my method in angular2 app:

```
  let url = `${this.config.ApiUrl}/api/cases/${this.trader.id}`;
  this.authService.AuthPut(url, 'OPENED')

AuthPut(url: string, data: any, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Response> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);

    if (options) {
        options = this._setRequestOptions(options);
    } else {
        options = this._setRequestOptions();
    }
    return this.http.put(url, body, options);
}

private _setAuthHeaders(user: any): void {
    this.authHeaders = new Headers();
    this.authHeaders.append('Authorization', this.getAuthorizationHeaderValue());
    if (this.authHeaders.get('Content-Type')) {

    } else {
        this.authHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json;');
        this.authHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    }
}

private _setRequestOptions(options?: RequestOptions) {
    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
        this._setAuthHeaders(this.user);
    }
    if (options) {
        options.headers.append(this.authHeaders.keys[0], this.authHeaders.values[0]);
    } else {
        options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.authHeaders, body: '', method: 'GET' });
    }

    return options;
}
```

Comment: Does your trader has a id? And does your trader id is from type integer?

Comment: oh yes. it actually calls the api as well with the right trader id. only thing is the sting parameter is taking null

Comment: It would seem as though you are going about this in an unorthodox fashion. You shouldn't JSON.stringify the body. You should pass the body as an object. Create a C# object that has the properties you are expecting from the request and make the type of object expected after the FromBody attribute be of that type. Then it should work just fine. Update your question with the shape of the data to be passed to the UI and we should be able to help you.